# $(ProjectDir) prebuild event macro incorrect

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I have a pre-build event.

I have a project located at `C:\Project\src\Project\`, with a batch file `doSomething.bat` at `C:\Project\src\Project\doSomething.bat`.

In my pre-build event, I want to run `doSomething.bat`, so I have this script:

```
cd $(ProjectDir) && call ./doSomething.bat
```

However, `$(ProjectDir)` actually places me in `C:\Project\src\Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\`

This is not what the documentation states. How can I fix this?

Comment: I also found this incorrect for the macro "$(OutDir)" in the .net core project, I guess the reason for this issue is related to the new change for MSBuild support for .NET Core projects, with a simplified csproj project format that makes it easier to edit by hand, without the need to unload the project. Now, the issue 1569 in Martin Ullrich`s answer have explained the reason for this issue. Did he answer to solve your problem? If not, please let us to know the latest status about this issue.

Comment: An unbelievable oversight by MS here. Just an out and out bug that hasn't been fixed for whatever reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SDK-based projects `PreBuildEvent` and `PostBuildEvent` are evaluated too early to receive "final" values for a lot of properties, they are even considered to be deprecated (see https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1569)

As a quick workaround, you can use `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` or `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` which will give you the directory that the `.csproj` file is in.

For a more integrated solution, you can add a custom target to the csproj file like this (no `cd` step needed):

```
<Target Name="MyAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="test.bat" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1569#issuecomment-289939906) on how to make it resolve common macros and properties correctly (discussed on the thread, mentioned by @MartinUllrich).

See an example on the link. The key points of the solution is to modify the `.csproj` file so:

- The root tag stays without attributes: just `<Project>` rather than `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`
- Import `Sdk.props` at the beginning: `<Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" Project="Sdk.props" />`
- Import `Sdk.targets` before pre-, post- build events: `<Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" Project="Sdk.targets" />`

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen after I'd manually edited the project file.

I'd inadvertently moved this line:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

to *below* the `<PropertyGroup><PreBuildEvent> ...` elements from its original position *above* them.

Try this:

1. Open your project file, eg `MyProject.csproj` (or `MyProject.vbproj`).
2. Find `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` (or `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />`).
3. Move it to directly above the beginning of your build event elements (`<PropertyGroup><PreBuildEvent> ...`)
4. Clean the project/solution, recompile and you should be good.

**Note:** I also had another project that had this error out of the box so I think it can "just happen" as well.